# File upload using robot class or similar to autoit in selenium using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can you tell me other Ways to File upload except sendkey(using robot class or similar to autoit) in selenium using python. In my code sendkeys is not working and My Site do not have textbox to copy the path

Comment: you can google for more results

Comment: Did not get any useful code

Comment: Can anyone describe

Comment: can you explain the scenario more?  Is it that you click a button on a web page and it opens the file explorer?

Comment: I want to upload "X.html" file on some chat group. And Yes  When I click a button on a web page and it opens the System file explorer to select a file and When I select the file It just upload .